# How to display two image every page in fpdf using php and sql

Tags: php, fpdf

Im working with fpdf that display two images every page, but it only display one picture every page.
Here is my code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmti = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM inv_images WHERE id = :id");
$stmti->bindParam(':id',$id);
$stmti->execute();
$imageList = $stmti->fetchAll();

foreach ($imageList as $image) { 
        $pdf->AddPage();        
        $pdf->Image('dealers_picture/'.$image['name'],30,30,160,110);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

//Database Connection
function con($db){
$con=mysqli_connect($db['server'],$db['username'],$db['password'],$db['database']);
if(!$con){echo "Check Server Connection and Database"; exit;}else{return $con;}
}

//Data Query
function qry($con,$qryx,$suc,$err)
{
    $qr=mysqli_query($con,$qryx);
    if(!$qr){
        return mysqli_error($con);
    }else{
        if(mysqli_num_rows($qr)>0){
        $ar=array();
        while($dbd=mysqli_fetch_array($qr))
        {$ar[]=$dbd;} return $ar;
        }else
        {return $err;}
    }
}
//connect the database
$db=array("server"=>"127.0.0.1","username"=>"root","password"=>"manju!@#123","database"=>"images");
$con = con($db);

//write query to get the images in array
$query = "select * from gallery order by id desc";
$qry = qry($con,$query,"success","error");
$images=array();
if(is_array($qry))
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($qry);$i+=1)
    {
        $images[$i]=$qry[$i]["image"];
        //echo $qry[$i]["image"]."<br/>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo $qry;  
}
//var_dump($images);
$imgs =$images;

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
//$pdf->Output();

//$images = '["images/er.jpg","images/dc.jpg","images/g.jpg","images/7.jpg","images/4.jpg","images/2.jpg"]';
//$imgs = json_decode($images);

//var_dump($imgs);
$i=0;

for($i=0;$i<count($imgs);$i+=1)
{
    if(isset($imgs[$i+1])){
    
    
    if($i % 2==0){
        $pdf->Image($imgs[$i],10,12,40,30,'','');
        $pdf->Image($imgs[$i+1],60,12,40,30,'','');
        //echo $imgs[$i]." ".$imgs[$i+1];
        //echo "<hr/>";
        $pdf->AddPage();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $pdf->Image($imgs[$i],10,12,40,30,'','');
        //echo $imgs[$i];
        //echo "<hr/>";
    }
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: I did it using pdo, but the problem is, I have only 2 image, but it shows 3, the first image was repeat to new page.

Comment: It's working now, thank you once again :)

Comment: if(isset($imgs[$i+1])){
      if($i % 2==0){
          $pdf->Image($imgs[$i],30,30,160,110,'','');
          $pdf->Image($imgs[$i+1],30,160,160,110,'','');

      }else{
       $pdf->AddPage();
       $pdf->Image($imgs[$i],30,30,160,110,'','');
      }
     }
     else
     {
         if($i % 2==0){
          $pdf->Image($imgs[$i],30,30,160,110,'','');
      }

     }

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are overlapping the pictures, increase the X size in second image.

```
$images=['image1','image2'];
$x=30 
for ($i = 0; $<2 ; $i++) { 
    $pdf->AddPage();        
    $pdf->Image('dealers_picture/'.$image[$i],$x,30,160,110);
    $x+=200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
//$pdf->Output();

$images = '["images/er.jpg","images/dc.jpg","images/g.jpg","images/7.jpg","images/4.jpg","images/2.jpg"]';
$imgs = json_decode($images);
//var_dump($imgs);


for($i=0;$i<count($imgs);$i+=1)
{
if(isset($imgs[$i+1])){


if($i % 2==0){
    $pdf->Image($imgs[$i],10,12,40,30,'','');
    $pdf->Image($imgs[$i+1],60,12,40,30,'','');
    //echo $imgs[$i]." ".$imgs[$i+1];
    //echo "<hr/>";
    $pdf->AddPage();
    }
}
else
{
    $pdf->Image($imgs[$i],10,12,40,30,'','');
    //echo $imgs[$i];
    //echo "<hr/>";
}
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: It's working with no database,  how it will work with the database? or what is the syntax of the array when using sql?

Comment: I given one more code below pls check

Comment: How about displaying multiple records with a single ID?